# Macro substitution on a dynamically linked shared object

Tags: c, macros, dynamic-linking, shared-objects

I have a compiled source code executable which has redefined `malloc()` with a custom function `CustMalloc()` using macro substitution.

As seen from the below backtrace, the compiled source code executable is supposed to be dynamically linked with **libMRegAccess.so** and **libusb-1.0.so.0 shared objects**. Both these shared objects were **independently compiled** and they have no means of knowing the above macro substitution during their compilation.

Now, **bsd-asprintf.c** I presume is a linux source file and the call to `asprintf()` and `vasprintf()` are called from the **libusb-1.0.so.0 shared object** when executing, which in turn tries to call `malloc()`.

I'm unable to understand why the custom function `CustMalloc()` is getting called instead of the actual `malloc()`.

FYI, the semaphore that is required in this backtrace is not yet created and hence the crash. The expectation is that the `CustMalloc()` should not be invoked in this code flow as the call is being made from an independently built shared object.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to LWP 1269]
0x0000007fb7f896cc in __new_sem_wait_fast () from /lib//libpthread.so.0
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000007fb7f896cc in __new_sem_wait_fast () from /lib//libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000007fb7f898fc in sem_wait@@GLIBC_2.17 () from /lib//libpthread.so.0
#2  0x0000000001b09000 in SemTake (SemId=0x0) at <compiled_source_code.c>
#3  0x0000000000d6cffc in ContextLock () at <compiled_source_code.c>
#4  0x0000000000d993e4 in CustMalloc (size=128) at <compiled_source_code.c>
#5  0x0000000001c88a2c in vasprintf (str=0x7fb5eaf5f8, fmt=0x7fb7e8a640 "usb%s", ap=...) at bsd-asprintf.c:61
#6  0x0000000001c88c50 in asprintf (str=0x7fb5eaf5f8, fmt=0x7fb7e8a640 "usb%s") at bsd-asprintf.c:120
#7  0x0000007fb7e853cc in linux_enumerate_device () from /usr/lib/libusb-1.0.so.0
#8  0x0000007fb7e854c4 in sysfs_scan_device () from /usr/lib/libusb-1.0.so.0
#9  0x0000007fb7e85b80 in op_init () from /usr/lib/libusb-1.0.so.0
#10 0x0000007fb7e7dd1c in libusb_init () from /usr/lib/libusb-1.0.so.0
#11 0x0000007fb7ea65fc in cyusb_open(unsigned short, unsigned short) () from /usr/lib/libMRegAccess.so
#12 0x0000007fb7ea33f4 in InitDefaultUSBConn () from /usr/lib/libMRegAccess.so
#13 0x0000007fb7ea58e0 in openDefaultUSBDriver () from /usr/lib/libMRegAccess.so
#14 0x00000000010ddd94 in InitDrv () at <compiled_source_code.c>
#15 ... at <compiled_source_code.c>
#16 ... at <compiled_source_code.c>
#17 ... at <compiled_source_code.c>
#18 ... at <compiled_source_code.c>
#19 0x0000007fb7f80fd0 in start_thread () from /lib//libpthread.so.0
#20 0x0000007fb7d8cf60 in ?? () from /lib//libc.so.6
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm unable to understand why the custom function CustMalloc() is getting called instead of the actual malloc()

This appears to be happening because *you* compiled and linked `bsd-asprintf.c` (with your macro redefinition) into your main executable.

You can tell that `asprintf` and `CustMalloc` are part of your binary, because their addresses are very different from other library routines (such as `linux_enumerate_device` or `sem_wait`).

If you want to know where `asprintf` is defined (which archive library or object file it comes from), relink your executable with `-Wl,-y,asprintf` flag, and the linker will tell you.